# Adding links to Font Awesome icons

Tags: html, hyperlink, font-awesome

The links on the font awesome icons were not working in the following container.

```html
<div class="profile_wrap">
  <div class="profile_tile">
    <img class="pp-image" src="http://maduk.uk.w3pcloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/stuart-pic.png">
    <div class="social_area profile_animate-text">
      <a href="http://www.gmail.com" class="icon-block"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
      <a href="http://www.linkedin.co.uk"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="profile_text">
      <h1 class="profile_animate-text">Lorem ipsum.</h1>
      <h2 class="profile_animate-text">More lorem ipsum bacon ipsum.</h2>
      <p class="profile_animate-text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet pork belly tri-tip turducken, pancetta bresaola pork chicken meatloaf. Flank sirloin strip steak prosciutto kevin turducken.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I fixed the issue by adding the following CSS `z-index:999` on the elements.

the problem was because they was sitting at the back of the div and there was another div in font, this made them not possible to click.

Comment: have you linked the font awesonm css file? If yes check the developer console and see if you get any errors.

Comment: Updated your question, check the snippet, it works fine.

Comment: Yup, the snippet is working ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
.profile_animate-text {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```